# How can I open an unpermitted folder in external HDD?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, hard-drive, external-hdd, inspiron

I had an DELL Inspirion N-5030 which I used till yesterday. Today I purchased another Dell Inspirion 15 (3000 Series). The previous was installed with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and this laptop is installed with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The previous hard drive is encased as external HDD Now by Mistake I had a protected folder created by Ubuntu 14.04 in previous laptop. Currently while trying to open that particular folder, I am unable to get access into it. How can I retrieve that folder? Other folders are accessible till now.

Comment: What do you mean by protected? If its owned by a different user, you can just retake it with `chown`.

Answer (score 0):

Check folder permissions with:

`ls -l /folder/path | grep foldername`

Result will be like that:

```
drwx------
```

First d is mean that this is a directory. rwx is mean access flags:

"r" : read allows the user to list the directory contents;

"w" : write allows the user to write, modify and delete files in this directory;

"x" : executing allows the user to enter into this directory;

"-" : flag is rest.

The first triple is relate to root, second to owner and third to other users.  To change access right you may use chmod utility.

```
chmod XXX /path/to/folder
```

where XXX determine wishful rights to set.

For make XXX you need to know that

0 mean reset

1 mean executing

2 mean writing

4 mean reading

Calculate XXX is very simple. It's just an addition of required rights. For instance if you need read and write access you need calculate 2+4=6. If you need all access 1+2+4=7.
So, chmode 754 is mean that:

root (7) have accesss to all (1+2+5=7)

owner (5) have access to execute and to read (1+4=5)

other users (4) have access only to read

Of cource, this utility must be executiong as root. So, use

```
sudo chmod XXX /path/to/folder
```